# PHP / Windows - Opendir() fails opening subdirectories within symbolic linked directories

Tags: php, windows, symlink

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I'm unable to open a subdirectory within a symboliclink'd directory. I've confirmed that the paths are correct (even copy & pasted the path into explorer, which parsed it fine). This is a strange, annoying, bug :|.

**Example:**

> C:\folder\symbolic_link\dir1\dir2 - opening dir2 fails.
>
> C:\folder\symbolic_link\dir1 - works
>
> C:\folder\real_directory\dir1\dir2 - works
>
> C:\folder\real_directory\dir1 - works

Comment: It works in explorer, but does the iis_user have permissions to view it?

Comment: @Dan Thx! but I'm running apache (XAMPP LAMP stack), it seems to be a bug with php's opendir(). I found a php bug report dating back to 2008 that hasn't been fixed in 5.3 :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally found a hack to solve this bug in php's handling of symlinks on windows. The bug occurs when recursively iterating through files/directories using `opendir()`. If a symlink to a directory exists in the current directory, `opendir()` will fail to read the directories in the directory symlink. It is caused by something funky in php's statcache, and can be resolved by calling `clearstatcache()` before calling `opendir()` on the directory symlink (also, the parent directory's file-handle must be closed).

Here is an example of the fix:

```
<?php

class Filesystem
{
    public static function files($path, $stats = FALSE)
    {
        clearstatcache();

        $ret = array();
        $handle = opendir($path);
        $files = array();

        // Store files in directory, subdirectories can't be read until current handle is closed & statcache cleared.
        while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
            {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }

        // Handle _must_ be closed before statcache is cleared, cache from open handles won't be cleared!
        closedir($handle);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
        clearstatcache($path);

            if (is_dir($path . '/' . $file))
            {
                $dir_files = self::files($path . '/' . $file);

                foreach ($dir_files as $dir_file)
                {
                    $ret[] = $file . '/' . $dir_file;
                }
            }
            else if (is_file($path . '/' . $file))
            {
                $ret[] = $file;
            }
        }

        return $ret;
    }
}

var_dump(filessystem::files('c:\\some_path'));
```

**Edit:** It seems that `clearstatcache($path)` must be called before any file-handling functions on the symlink'd dir. Php isn't caching symlink'd dirs properly.